# Linux find folder and rename

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to rename all `.hg_gg` folders in `/var/www` to `.hg`. How can I do it?
I know how to rename `.hg` to `.hg_gg`.

```
find /var/www -name ".hg" -exec bash -c 'mv $0 $0_gg' {} \;
```

but don't know how to make reverse change.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of these folders?

Comment: I want to rename /var/www/test/.hg_gg/ to /var/www/test/.hg/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
find /var/www -name ".hg_gg" -execdir bash -c 'mv {} .hg' \;
```

You need to use a special syntax defined by find: `{}` is the placeholder for the current file name. Check the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) for that. Also it is **important** to use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`. `execdir` changes the current working directory to the folder where the found directory is located. Otherwise it would do something like this `mv /var/www/.hg_gg ./.hg`

You can speed up things a bit when restricting find to find folders only using `-type d`:

```
find /var/www -type d -name ".hg_gg" -execdir bash -c 'mv {} .hg' \;
```

Comment: I believe OP wants reverse of this

Comment: Yeah he says, but he shows different code.. I'm not sure what he wants. I'm hope at least he does.. ;) Have updated the code

Comment: mv: cannot move `/var/www/test/.hg_gg' to `.hg/.hg_gg': Directory not empty

Comment: Ok, I see. Use `execdir`

Comment: Great! It works, thanks! I only added -depth param so it doesnot show me error that file is not found.

Answer (score 5):

Consider this find command with `-execdir` and `-prune` options:

```
find /var/www/ -type d -name ".hg_gg" -execdir mv '{}' '.gg' \; -prune
```

- `-execdir` will execute the command in each subdirectory
- `-prune`  causes find to not descend into the current file

Comment: PS: Note that without `-prune` option you will get errors like `./.hg_gg: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

Not a one liner, but you could do this:

```
for file in `find /var/www -name ".hg_gg"`; do
    mv $file `echo $file | sed 's/hg_gg$/hg/'`
done
```

Comment: I would do a [ -d ] test to confirm the file is a directory to before calling mv.